# Can I have two step definitions for one step when having java8 lambda style

Tags: kotlin, cucumber, cucumber-java

After switching to lambda step definitions for my glue code, I have the problem that some steps had two step-definitions (one for When and one for Given). Now it seems that lambda-style step-definitions cannot have two cucumberexpressions

Please, no advisories of leaving one of the Regex. I'm doing all the stuff in German and there is a spelling problem when having the same sentence with "Angenommen" or "Wenn" (which is Given and When)

The code example is from a kotlin-project!

```
Given("FAQ is open"),
When("FAQ-page is open") {
            getWebDriver.gotoUrl(PageUrls.FAQ, FAQPage::class, testDataContainer)
            getPage(FAQPage::class).waitForPageLoaded()
        }
```

Is there a way to do it in java8-lambda Style?

Comment: Can't you write `Given("abc") { commonMethod() }` and `When("abc") { commonMethod() }` ?

Comment: U can try making the `-page` part optional. `FAQ(-page) is open` or even alternate `FAQ/FAQ-page is open`